# Image hosted on AWS is not displayed in Gmail

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, nodemailer

I'm sending an email from node js using node-mailer. The html format includes an image hosted on AWS S3, when i open this, is shown great, including the image. Is also shown fine when i see the email in hotmail, but when i check the same email in Gmail, the image is not shown, is just the white space. I have tried a few things, but a don't know what is actually happening. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you sure that gmail isn't blocking the image by default? Typically in the gmail webmail client, there is a link near the top of the email that tells gmail to reload the email message, with all images shown.

Comment: I already did and unfortunately is not that!

Comment: Please enumerate "tried a few things" as the few things you may have tried won't necessarily line up with the few things we might try. Also, that will avoid "try this" "already tried that" messages. Also, any messages in console when you view the email?

Comment: 3 things: 1. I check the gmail configuration about using images. 2. Searching I found in this page an idea as solution: adding some properties to the html img tag. 3. I verified the same email that I send in hotmail and others, but the problem is only on Gmail, I have tried sending other images and not the same, but is the same problem. ... No message in console, just the positive message from node mailer.

Comment: @dbmdlr, any update on this? we are facing the same issue